# Variable redefined by fast clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am running into an issue with my code. If a user clicks very quickly, it is possible to redefine the `originalHeight` value, which I am battling to wrap my head around. Could someone point me in the right direction so that I can understand why this is even possible?

HTML:

```
onclick="releaseElement()"
```

JS:

```javascript
function releaseElement() {
  if (typeof originalHeight === 'undefined' || flag !== "open") {
      originalHeight = $('#element').height();
      flag = "closed";
  }
  if (flag === "closed") {
      flag = "open";
      var height = ($(window).height() - 60);
      $('#element').stop().animate({height: height});
      $('#anotherelement').stop().animate({marginTop: "-205px"});
      return;
  }
  if (flag === "open") {
      $('#element').stop().animate({height: originalHeight});
      $('#anotherelement').stop().animate({marginTop: "-105px"});
      flag = "closed";
      return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a Click event at all?

Comment: Please create a code snippet that reproduce the specific problem.

Comment: My problem is that originalHeight can be redefined if the user clicks very quickly on the element before the defining if statement has completed itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but please check if your code requires a "else" in the following manner...

```
if (flag === "closed") {
      flag = "open";
      var height = ($(window).height() - 60);
      $('#element').stop().animate({height: height});
      $('#anotherelement').stop().animate({marginTop: "-205px"});
      return;
  }
else
  if (flag === "open") {
      $('#element').stop().animate({height: originalHeight});
      $('#anotherelement').stop().animate({marginTop: "-105px"});
      flag = "closed";
      return;
  }
```

Because if your flag is closed initially, clicking it multiple times would call if(flag==="close") and then if(flag==="open") all the time.